# How to dynamically extract data from XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have a string variable, containing XML data and I was wondering if there is an easy way to extract fields and data from the file. Through an iterative **generic** way, without specifying name of the tags in the code.

Comment: why didn't you read the php manual?

Comment: Well, in its defense, I had some difficulty finding simpleXML the first time. The PHP Manual is pretty big, and a little hint from SO users is quick and useful.

Comment: I am agree to Chouchenos

Comment: I read the SimpleXML but I didn't find -at least so far- a way to do this dynamically. Do I have to change the code every time depending on the tags or it's possible to write one that works for all?

Comment: If you only have children and no attributes, for you can do like example 1 on this page http://www.php.net/manual/fr/simplexmlelement.children.php but in an iterative way (a function doing a `foreach` of `foreach` of `foreach`) The SimpleXMLElement works mostly like an array (you do have `count()` for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SimpleXML.

Load your data with [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-string.php)
And then you can make a loop to parse the xml into an array thanks to the [SimpleXML class](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.simplexmlelement.php)

As it is called, it's pretty simple to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many XML parsing libraries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), each has its own strengths and annoyances, so you're going to find a broad range of solutions.

However, here is a nice snipplet that is small, fast and functions *regardless of what libraries are installed* because it's a regex.

You [feed it an XML string and it returns an array of the whole dynamic structure](http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/445):

```
$xml = file_get_contents('example.xml');
$data = xml2array($xml);
echo "<pre>" . print_r($data, true ) . "</pre>";
```

---

The function:

```
function xml2array($xml) {
 $xmlary = array();
 $reels = '/<(\w+)\s*([^\/>]*)\s*(?:\/>|>(.*)<\/\s*\\1\s*>)/s';
 $reattrs = '/(\w+)=(?:"|\')([^"\']*)(:?"|\')/';
 preg_match_all($reels, $xml, $elements);
 foreach ($elements[1] as $ie => $xx) {
   $xmlary[$ie]["name"] = $elements[1][$ie];
   if ($attributes = trim($elements[2][$ie])) {
     preg_match_all($reattrs, $attributes, $att);
     foreach ($att[1] as $ia => $xx)
       $xmlary[$ie]["attributes"][$att[1][$ia]] = $att[2][$ia];
   }
   $cdend = strpos($elements[3][$ie], "<");
   if ($cdend > 0) {
     $xmlary[$ie]["text"] = substr($elements[3][$ie], 0, $cdend - 1);
   }
   if (preg_match($reels, $elements[3][$ie]))
     $xmlary[$ie]["elements"] = xml2array($elements[3][$ie]);
   else if ($elements[3][$ie]) {
     $xmlary[$ie]["text"] = $elements[3][$ie];
   }
 }
 return $xmlary;
}
```